# Working with duration of multiple upload

Tags: javascript, web

I am completely lost and need help here. The code below works just fine in showing duration for each uploaded file but what I want is it show total duration for all files in hh:mm:ss format. Also I would like to add a feature to remove files from the list and which that triggers the subtraction or removal of that particular duration file. Thanks in advance.

```js
var myVideos = [];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function setFileInfo(files) {
  myVideos.push(files[0]);
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
    var duration = video.duration;
    myVideos[myVideos.length-1].duration = duration;
    updateInfos();
  }
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
}

function updateInfos() {
  document.querySelector('#infos').innerHTML = "";
  for(i=0; i<myVideos.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#infos').innerHTML + ="<div>" + myVideos[i].name + " duration: " + myVideos[i].duration + '</div>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
  <span>- Try Upload -</span> 
  <input type="file" class="upload" id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)">
</div>
<div id="infos"></div>
```

Please add the extra modification to the snippet, I'm not much of a coder.

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I've searched everywhere with no luck, it's been over a month now. So please help. If you need clarification comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.duration` property returns seconds, you can store, add and subtract these seconds and later output them in `hh:mm:ss` format.

For example you could use the following `formatSeconds` function:

```js
const formatSeconds = seconds => new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);

let myVideos = [];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function setFileInfo(files) {
  myVideos.push(files[0]);
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
    var duration = video.duration;
    myVideos[myVideos.length - 1].duration = duration;
    updateInfos();
  }
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);;
}

function updateInfos(deleteName) {
  let info = document.querySelector('#infos');
  info.innerHTML="";
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = myVideos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let v = myVideos[i];
    if (deleteName === myVideos[i].name) {
      myVideos.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      info.innerHTML += "<div class='row' data-name='" + v.name + "'>" + 
                            "<div class='close' onclick=remove(this)>&times</div>" +
                             v.name + ", duration: " + formatSeconds(v.duration) + 
                        "</div>";
      total += myVideos[i].duration;
    }
  }
  if (myVideos.length)
    info.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>Total: " + formatSeconds(total) + '</div>';
}

function remove(e) {
    updateInfos(e.parentNode.dataset.name);
}
```

```css
.close {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(35, 179, 119);
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgb(74, 72, 72);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.row {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#infos {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
  <span>- Try Upload -</span> 
  <input type="file" class="upload" id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)">
</div>
<div id="infos"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, I get your point but I want the times to be from the uploaded files, can you integrate this to the my snippet.

Comment: It works but I was hoping it was going to be like this fiddle but instead of image size be a audio/video duration. http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/r0taz01L/4/

Comment: @Thulani I've added the remove button, check the updated code.

Comment: Thanks so much @KirillSimonov, exactly what I need.

Comment: How can I use this http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#sequential with the above code

Comment: Hi @Thulani! If you have a new question, feel free to ask it describing all details and what you already have. And then, if you provide a link to this question, I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: I came up with this https://jsfiddle.net/Thulani/3dhfq9zq/7/ I've been battle with putting the duration parts in this plugin. I want to use this form to get durations like the above code you made. Could you help with this one too?

Comment: I'll help you, but since it's not a part of this question, you should ask a new question

Comment: I'd appreciate that

Comment: So how is it coming along?

Comment: @Thulani did you create a new question?

Comment: But I undeleted it so here's a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063522/how-to-put-these-two-codes-together

Comment: Hey @KirillSomonov, why did you delete that post on total size? It was very useful and I wasn't quite done using it.

Comment: @ThulaniMabena hey! I thought that you didn't need it because you said that you were going to look for another plugin. But if you still need that code, I can undelete it (if you undelete the question first).

Comment: Done. I undeleted it